# jQuery Datepicker Show Current Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

**Datepicker script:**

```
$(function(){ 

         $( "#task_start_date").datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
         showOn: 'button',
         buttonImage :image_us,
         buttonImageOnly: true
        });
```

**HTML Input:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control validate[required,custom[date]]" name="task_start_date" id="task_start_date" />
```

When clicked in calendar icon, `dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',` outputs `27-Nov-2014` and shows the current date highlighted,

but `dateFormat: 'dd-M-y',` outputs `01-MAR-12` and shows `01-MAR-12` as highlighted instead of current.

I am using `jQuery Validation Engine` to validate the date format. The below fiddle works fine but not with the expected date format.

JS Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw56tnej/12/)

Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly in my Chrome. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: For me too the date is shown correctly on latest Chrome/Firefox and IE9+

Comment: True. But somehow it still show the validation message for correct date format. And if I change the `dateFormat: 'dd-M-y',` the calendar does not show current date but the date coming from DB viz. 01-MAR-14

Comment: You might want to check your regional settings or try another browser. See if the problem still occurs

Answer (score 0):

I saw your JS Fiddle.
I think, you have a mistake on RegExp result which is null.

I tried to change your RegExp.

`new RegExp(/([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\d{4})/);`

Change to

`new RegExp(/([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\d{2,4})/);`

And Change

`var isOk = (d.getFullYear() == year && d.getMonth() == months.indexOf(month) && d.getDate() == day);`

to

`var isOk = (d.getYear() == (year).slice(-2) && d.getMonth() == months.indexOf(month) && d.getDate() == day);`

Below full code. Second changed version.

```
$( "#task_start_date").datepicker({
    monthNamesShort: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-y',
    defaultDate: '18-Nov-14',
    onClose: function (date) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[0-1])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(\d{2,4})/);
        var match = pattern.exec(date);
        if (match == null)
             return false;

        var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        var year = match[3];
        var month = match[2];
        var day = match[1];

        var d = new Date(year, months.indexOf(month), day);
        var isOk = (d.getYear() == (year).slice(-2) && d.getMonth() == months.indexOf(month) && d.getDate() == day);
                alert(isOk);    }
});
$("#task_start_date").datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I change the `dateFormat: 'dd-M-y',` the calendar does not display current date highlighted. Also is it possible to allow uppercase month as well.

Comment: It wired. I have checked class name ui-state-active. `<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">`

Comment: The input is pre-filled with some previous date and when calendar shows that same date instead of current, when format is changed to `dd-M-y`.

Comment: And how can ` var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]` be allowed in `JAN` format ?

Comment: Thanks, but here I am not using `setDate` as its coming from DB in `01-MAR-12` format. And still it expects `01-Mar-12` format to be valid even after I pasted your code. Also if dateformat is `dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'` it returns false.